# Writing a generic makefile for C and ASSEMBLY files

Tags: c, linux, assembly, makefile

I'm building a linux kernel module written in ASM and C.
individually, the code can compile, but I can't figure out how to compile it together (Both C and ASM files).
I have 2 c files (`entry.c`, `cpu_checks.c`), 1 header file (`cpu_checks.h`) and 1 assembly file (`cpu.asm`).

I'm trying to compile all to `.o` object files and then link them together. My problem is that for some resaon the makefile doesn't recognize the rule for building `.asm` files.

This is how my makefile looks as of now:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=n
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

DRIVER_DIR=path/to/driver/dir

CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
LD = ld
LDFLAGS = -melf_i386
NASM = nasm
NASMFLAGS = -f elf64 -F stabs 

obj-m := hyper.o
hyper-objs := $(patsubst $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.asm, $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(DRIVER_DIR)/*.asm)) 
hyper-objs += $(patsubst $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.c, $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(DRIVER_DIR)/*.c))

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(hyper-objs)

# Makefile recognizes this rule.
$(DRIVER_DIR)/%.o: $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<

# Makefile doesn't recognize this rule.
$(DRIVER_DIR)/%.o: $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.asm
    $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~

real_clean:
    rm -f *.o *.ko *~
```

I'm not very good at writing makefiles, so I might (even probably) have written something wrong. If not, what can I do to et the makefile to recognize that rule?

Comment: The first matching rule for an out-of-date/missing .o file is pinned to a .c file. The latter rule never comes into play. Move your asm-only generated .o targets to a different folder (anything, so long as it isn't where other .o files are stuffed), and compile them with a rule indicating *that* folder. Effectively, build two distinct .o generating chains: one for asm sources, the other for c sources, each putting their object code in their own target folders. Then include both resulting .o lists in your final link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `default:` rule doesn't have any dependencies to check.  So it will just run the commands under it without building any of the .o files that you need.  Adding $(hyper-objs) as a dependency will ensure all the .o files are built first

```
default: $(hyper-objs)
```

Comment: Also, you'd normally want to have a separate rule for building `a.out`(?) from `$(hyper-objs)`, with that rule running the `make` on `modules` or whatever.  You normally want the `default:` to just set the default, not have a bunch of commands that can *only* be run via `make default`.